# Creating a File and then Loop for an Incrementing Value

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to create a loop that creates a file named "/tmp/newfile.txt" and creates 29 lines of text. Line 1 should read: "I see 0 sheep". For each line, 1 sheep should be added and a new line created to reflect that until 29 sheep (and lines) are reached.

```
x = 0
myDoc = myDoc.readfiles("/tmp/newfile.txt", "r+") 
myDoc.write("I see" + str(x) + "sheep")
for line in myDoc.readfiles():
  x = x + 1
  myDoc.append(x)
  print(myDoc)
if x == 30
  break;
```

First, what I tried to do is create a new file and put it into a variable (myDoc) that would open it. I specified w+ so that I would have the ability to read the file and write on it. I gave the changing number a variable 'x'.

The function I intended to, for each line in the file, write "I see x sheep". Afterward, add 1 to the current value of x and append it so it's added to the file. After this, print it so I can see the line(s). Once that value reached 30, cease the loop because 29 is the number of lines I need.

My errors have to do with indentation and nothing being printed at all. I am **extremely** new to this.

Comment: You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: Indeed your indentation is wrong; any basic tutorial will cover that; in addition, since your file is created empty, it contains no line, so `for line in myDoc:` will not do anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a couple of issues in the code:

1. Indentation / Syntax Errors - It seems that you are using Python, which follows strict indentation and whitespace rules. An indent is inserted when you enter a new local scope / new control flow / enter an if/elif/else statement or a while or for loop, to separate it from the current scope.
   You'd need to remove the space on the left side on line 3 and line 6.
   Also, on line 8 there should be a colon(`:`) after the `if x==30`.
2. The mode used (`w+`) isn't going to work as expected.
   This mode overwrites a file if it already exists and allows you to read and write to that file. Instead, you would need the `r+` mode.
   There's a great explanation & flowchart in this answer explaining the various file modes - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/13307211
3. The for loop can't iterate over `myDoc`.
   The `open` function gives a file object (`TextIOWrapper`), which can't be iterated over. You could use the `myDoc.readfiles()` method, which returns a list of lines present in the file and loop over that - `for line in myDoc.readfiles()`.
4. printing myDoc and using `.append()` with myDoc wouldn't work as expected. It's representing a file object, which doesn't have an append method. Also, I feel like there might have been some mixed logic here - were you trying to iterate over myDoc like an array and hence pushing value to it?
   I'd suggest removing the append part as the past value of `x` isn't going to be needed for what you want to do.

After applying the above, you should end up with code that looks like this -

```
x = 0
myDoc = open("./newfile.txt", "r+")

for line in myDoc.readlines():
    myDoc.write("I see" + str(x) + "sheep\n")
    x = x + 1
    if x == 30:
        break
```

Now, this doesn't exactly do what you want it to do...

The first thing we should do is update the for loop - a for loop should be structured in a way where it has a start, an end, and an increment, or it should iterate over a range of values. Python has a neat range function that allows you to iterate between values.

```py
for x in range(1, 10):
    print(x)
```

the above would print values from 1 to 10, excluding 10.
updating our for loop, we can change the code to -

```
myDoc = open("./newfile.txt", "r+")

for x in range(1, 30):
    myDoc.write("I see" + str(x) + "sheep")
```

we could also use a while loop here -

```py
myDoc = open("./newfile.txt", "r+")

i = 1
while (i <= 30):
    myDoc.write("I see" + str(x) + "sheep")
    i += 1
```

this makes the file but without the lines and without the right formatting. `"I see " + str(x) + " sheep"` should fix the sentence, but to print the string on multiple lines instead of the same line, you would need to use the newline character(`\n`) and add it at the end of the string -

```py
myDoc = open("./newfile.txt", "r+")

for x in range(1, 30):
    myDoc.write("I see" + str(x) + "sheep\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome!

I'm always impressed to see how many different ways one can achieve the same solution. I really appreciated your input here, because it gave me more to consider when I tackle my next challenge. :)

I was able to achieve my result after going through your help. Thank you, kind stranger!